# How to include featured image URL in WordPress get_posts() json_encode()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to add to the foreach array to include the featured image URL and permalink.

How do I do that?

```
<?php
$posts_array = get_posts();

$send_array = array();
foreach ($posts_array as $key => $value) {
    $send_array[$key]['ID']           = $value->ID;
    $send_array[$key]['post_title']   = $value->post_title;
    $send_array[$key]['post_content'] = $value->post_content;
};
?>

<script>var getPost = <?php echo json_encode( $posts_array ); ?>;</script>
```

Comment: i update code check plz

Comment: There was an error present with your code. I still require the $key in order to reference the array positions.

Comment: try `var_dump($send_array);` after foreach

Comment: @IvanKaraman that outputs thumbnails, but still not visible in the array. It's not being sent in the json_encode()?

Comment: I figured it out. I was encoding the wrong array. It should have been the $send_array, not $posts_array. It all works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated**

try this

```
<?php
$posts_array = get_posts();
$send_array = array();
foreach ($posts_array as $_post) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $_post->ID );
    $send_array[] = array(
        'id' => $_post->ID;
        'post_title' => $_post->post_title,
        'post_content' => $_post->post_content,
        'permalink' => get_permalink($_post->ID),
        'thumbnail' => $image[0]
    );
};
?>

<script>var getPost = <?php echo json_encode( $send_array ); ?>;</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried adding those parameters, however even your code is not including them in the array.

Comment: I realize this is outdated, but that is because ( $_post->ID ); it's missing a closing bracket,   ( $_post->ID ) );